# Edit tcp packets in pcap file

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I need to make tcpdump using **wireshark** or **tcpdump**
For some tcp streams in log I need full packet info.
But for tcp streams in log I need to remove all info except full uri info.

For this I'am going to use regular expressions.
If URI, http.request or http.response match some of regular expressions
then I need to store full tcp stream info.
If doesn't match --- then I need to remove all tcp stream info except full uri info.

I need it to reduce log size.

What tool do you advise for this ?
Or may be some php/python library will be helpful to create script that will filter log ?

Answer (score 1):

[**tcpick**](http://tcpick.sourceforge.net/) and [**tcpxtract**](http://tcpxtract.sourceforge.net/) are two tools available to filter and extract information from a `tcpdump` file. They are both open-source and available at sourceforge.net. You will have to write your own routine for how and what information you would like to extract. `tcpick` is fairly flexible regarding what parts of a packet you can view/extract.

Answer (score 0):

I use [TraceWrangler](https://www.tracewrangler.com/) in my projects, which despite being beta, works very well. It allows, in addition to editing the L2/L3 headers, to sanitize the packets.